# What is the best method to draw 2D components under an OpenGL ES View in Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, surfaceview, glsurfaceview

I'm looking to develop a game for Android using minimal 3D effects, but with mainly 2D graphics. I would prefer not to deal with OGLES Ortho projections and just stick with the simple 2D Canvas drawing provided by the Android SDK but everywhere I turn I only see solutions for using OGLES Ortho stuff.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a resource that would show me how to effectively render an OGLES view over a normal SurfaceView? Conceptually I think it would be something like having an Activity filled with a SurfaceView and an GLView on top of that, with the GLView's clear color being set to transparent. Am I at all on the right track with this? Is this approach even advisable or should I just bite the bullet and do everything with OpenGL?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use OpenGL you should first start [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html). In short, Android lets you use `GlSurfaceView` in combination with a `GlSurfaceView.Renderer` to interact with the underlying, native OpenGL.

If you want a more "guided" approach, [this](http://pragprog.com/book/kbogla/opengl-es-2-for-android) is the book I am reading now.

Once you get familiar with OpenGL, you might want to use an engine like [libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/). After playing with it for a while you mind find that you want a tool to create your world. You can use [this](https://www.iforce2d.net/rube/) Box2D editor.

RUBE is a Box2D editor (that uses the Box2D physics engine) that will output a JSON file that represents your world, so you will need a parser to convert the JSON file to Java so you can use it with the engine. Luckily there is [this](https://github.com/tescott/RubeLoader) project you can use for that.

Comment: I am actually more familiar with OpenGL than I am with Android development. This is also partially a learning exercise too, so I would rather not use an engine.

Comment: Then I suggest you read the first link and try to get a hold of that book. It is really good.

Comment: I've been following that all along actually, and it does not address my issue at all